# How to convert boolean value into int and vice versa in java?

Tags: java

In C++, 1 is treated as true and 0 is treated as false. So, internal conversion is possible in C++. But can this be possible in Java? Can we convert int to boolean or boolean into int as per our need in Java?

For Example, for [this problem on GeeksForGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-position-of-the-only-set-bit/), the C++ code might look like -

```
class Solution {
    public:
        int findPosition(int N) {
            if((N & (N -1)) or (N == 0)) return -1;
            return log2(N) + 1;
        }
};
```

How can write the same type of solution in Java?
Thank You.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: "*In C++, 1 is treated as true*" - technically, all non-zero values are treated as true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ implicitly converts int to boolean. In Java, you will have to do that explicitly by yourself.
To convert an int to boolean, just check whether it's not zero like this: `N != 0`

So you have to modify your original expression to something like this:

```java
if (((N & (N - 1)) != 0) || (N == 0))
```

Vice versa, to convert a boolean to an int, do something like this: `int i = boolValue ? 1 : 0;`